# Run commands that run in a shell as a script

Tags: linux, shell, shell-scripting, escaping

Running the following commands in a shell runs without issues:

```
ssh user@machine systemctl status my-service.service
ssh user@machine sudo systemctl stop my-service.service
scp -r ./my-service/* user@machine:/home/user/my-service
ssh user@machine chmod +x /home/user/my-service/my-service
ssh user@machine sudo systemctl start my-service.service
ssh user@machine sudo systemctl status my-service.service
```

However, putting this in a `deploy.sh` file results in none of the above being able to execute.

Errors:

- Invalid unit name "my-service" was escaped as "my-service\x0d" (maybe you should use systemd-escape?)
- Unit my-service\x0d.service could not be found.
- Invalid unit name "my-service.service" was escaped as "my-service.service\x0d" (maybe you should use systemd-escape?)
- Failed to stop my-service\x0d.service: Unit my-service.service\x0d.service not loaded.
  : No such file or directorynlock/
- chmod: cannot access '/home/user/my-service/my-service'$'\r': No such file or directory
- Invalid unit name "my-service.service" was escaped as "my-service.service\x0d" (maybe you should use systemd-escape?)
- Failed to start my-service.service\x0d.service: Unit my-service.service\x0d.service not found.
  Invalid unit name "my-service.service" was escaped as "my-service.service\x0d" (maybe you should use systemd-escape?)
- Unit my-service.service\x0d.service could not be found.

Some were broken up. It seems something related to escaping. For some reason adding a space at the end of the lines makes it sort of work but still not without errors.

Googling on the errors shows some hits about using `--` and adding it together with the trailing space makes some commands work but still giving an escaping error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would lay dollars to doughnuts that you edited this file on or from a *Windows* machine.

Linux uses \x0a (ASCII code 10) to separate lines within a file (or script).
Windows uses the combination of \x0d ("Carriage_Return", ASCII code 13) and \x0a ("Line Feed", ASCII 10) to do the *same* job.

Give a Windows-edited file to a Linux machine and it sees *every single line* as having an extraneous \x0d on the end.

Get yourself a *decent* Windows editor ([NotePad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/) is free and very highly recommended) or learn how to use **vi**.  Sure, it has its own learning curve, but some of its capabilities might surprise you!

Comment: I feel sooo stupid :-)

This was it, I edited the file in vscode. Changed from CRLF to LF in the lower right, saved it and it ran without issues.